# доступ к элементу object(stdClass)

Tags: php, классы

доброго времени суток.

есть такой вот объект:

```
$res = object(stdClass)#3 (3) { 
["size"]=> "16", 
["validator"]=> "", 
["validator-error"]=> "не работает", 
}
```

если я пишу `$res->size` , то получу `16` ,

но если пишу `$res->validator-error` , то получу только `Notice: Use of undefined constant error - assumed 'error' in ...`

как получить значение `validator-error` в этом объекте?

Comment: `$res->{'validator-error'}`

Comment: спасибо, помогло. перенесите комментарий в ответ, помечу принятым

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `php` имеется в наличии сложный (фигурный) синтаксис, он позволяет использовать сложные выражения. Любая скалярная переменная, элемент массива или свойство объекта, может быть представлена в строке этим синтаксисом. Просто надо написать выражение, заключив его в `{` и `}` .

Чаще это используется в строках. Но можно и вне их также спокойно делать.

Как пример

```
class foo {
    var $bar = 'I am bar.';
}

$foo = new foo();
$bar = 'bar';
$baz = array('foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'quux');
echo "{$foo->$bar}\n";
echo "{$foo->{$baz[1]}}\n";
```

Соответственно, если вы не хотите конвертировать свой объект в массив (а это тоже можно и законом не запрещено), а хотите обращаться к полю объекта, то можно использовать этот самый фигурный синтаксис.

В вашем случае это будет так:

```
$res->{'validator-error'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно так

```
((array)$res)['validator-error']
```

Answer (score -1):

> Правильное имя переменной должно начинаться с буквы или символа
>   подчеркивания и состоять из букв, цифр и символов подчеркивания в
>   любом количестве.

Переменная в PHP не может содержать символ "-".

Comment: Может это из БД вылезло или по API передали или еще как-либо. Не обязательно же всё сводится к тому, что в пхп варится. А вообще тут нет имени переменной с дефисом, так, на секундочку ;-)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский про то и речь, что это не переменная, и вытаскивать ее как свойство не стоит.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский к объяснению, почему конструкция `$res->validator-error` не работает

Comment: Почему не стоит? Если хочется вывести `echo СобщениеОбОшибке` то что теперь, умереть и не делать?